# Swift - Get case and value in enum with parameters

Tags: swift, swift4

I have this `enum`

```
public enum Format {
    case label(key: String)
    case textField(key: String)
    case image(key: String)
}
```

And I can use it like:

`Format.label(key: "abc")`

`Format.textField(key: "0.0")`

`Format.image(key: "mystringfile")`

When I try to get the value, I can do it with this:

```
let control = Format.label(key: "abc")
if case let Format.label(key) = control {
    tmp = key
} else if case let Format.image(key) = control {
    tmp = key
} else if case let Format.textField(key) = control {
    tmp = key
}
```

With that I can get the value, but I'm not finding the case `label`, `textfield` or `image`.

How I can find the enum that belongs that variable?

If I try to use something like this:
`control == Format.label`

I get the error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'Table.Format' and '(String) -> Format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may misunderstand your question but why not use a `switch`?

```
let control = Format.label(key: "abc") // or = Format.textField(key: "whatever") or = Format.image(key: "whatever")

let tmp: String
switch control {
case .label(let key):
    // It's a label, do what you need
    tmp = key
case .textField(let key):
    // It's a textField, do what you need
    tmp = key
case .image(let key):
    // It's a image, do what you need
    tmp = key
}
```

This lets you act on the type and get the value.